# Storing database version in the database itself

Tags: sql, database, configuration, version, h2

I'm writing a program that uses a h2 database to store data.
The database will be evolving as we add features to our software, but we still want users to be able to use an older version of the database with a newer version of the program. This way the program could automatically upgrade the database to the newer version (maybe asking first for confirmation from user).
To write this "database upgrader" we need to store the database version inside the database itself, so that it is possible to just move the database file (we're using file mode of the h2 database engine).
We tried doing something like this:

```
TABLE configuration (databaseVersion INT NOT NULL);
```

but this would mean having a table where only a single row is ever used without explicit checking of the row count.

Is there any better way to do this?
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good solution, if you *just* need to persist the database version.

Sometimes you need to persist more than one such 'global' settings, for example if your application consists of multiple modules, and each module has its own version. Or other things, like the location of the last backup. What I usually use is a `settings` table with a key/value pair, where both the `key` (the primary key of that table) and the `value` are of type `varchar`.